# How to solve "The apache2 configtest failed." in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, ubuntu-12.04

After update my php got the error:

The apache2 configtest failed. 
Output of config test was:

> apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_default.load:
>   Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Action 'configtest' failed.

Although I have installed
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Apache 2.4 was released after 12.04 LTS and so isn't a package in that version of Ubuntu.  How did you install Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear, one of the modules is missing.

> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_default.so: No such file or
>   directory

See these similar posts for solutions:

[Can't access website or restart apache2 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/581575/cant-access-website-or-restart-apache2-server)

Quoting @Benoit from that accepted answer:

> It's look like you have the file to load mod_authz_default but not the
>   library itself (the file with the .so extension). If you don't need
>   this functionality you should go to your /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
>   directory and delete mod_authz_default.load that should be a symlink
>   to a file of the same name in the /etc/apache2/mods-available/
>   directory.

https://superuser.com/questions/745484/ubuntu-14-04-upgrade-broke-apache2

https://askubuntu.com/questions/520033/apache-php5-problem-after-12-04-3-to-14-04-i-do-release-upgrade-server

Chances are you also upgraded Apache from 2.2 to 2.4, which requires a lot of work to make it fly again:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Sure @Iain, done. Which of course makes the question a duplicate now I found it for the original poster.

Comment: If I's a duplicate then post a link under the question and someone will likely come along and vote it as such. IRC as you have <3k rep you can flag as dupe too.